# partial refreshing a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I seperate refreshing rates in a gridview? I am using dropdownlist for filtering my data. If nothing selected it shows all of them. For example it is filtering with countries, and I want gridview to use different resfresh rates by country.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

  <h3>Northwind Employees</h3>

    <table cellspacing="10">            
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <table border="0">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">Country</td>
              <td><asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="CountryListBox" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                    DataSourceID="CountrySqlDataSource" 
                                    DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="Country" >
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="" >(Show All)</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Last Name</td>
              <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" id="LastNameTextBox" Text="*" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><asp:Button runat="server" id="FilterButton" Text="Filter Results" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td valign="top">                
          <asp:GridView ID="EmployeesGridView"
            DataSourceID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            AllowSorting="true"
            DataKeyNames="EmployeeID"     
            Gridlines="Both"
            RunAt="server">

            <HeaderStyle backcolor="Navy"
              forecolor="White"/>

            <RowStyle backcolor="White"/>

            <AlternatingRowStyle backcolor="LightGray"/>

            <EditRowStyle backcolor="LightCyan"/>

            <Columns>                  
              <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Employee ID" ReadOnly="true"/>                    
              <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"  HeaderText="First Name"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"   HeaderText="Last Name"/>                    
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Country"    HeaderText="Country"/>                    
            </Columns>                 
          </asp:GridView>
        </td>                
      </tr>            
    </table>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CountrySqlDataSource" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Employees"
      EnableCaching="True"
      CacheDuration="60"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>"
      RunAt="server" />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, Country FROM Employees"
      EnableCaching="True"
      CacheDuration="60"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>"
      FilterExpression="Country LIKE '{0}' AND LastName LIKE '{1}'"
      RunAt="server">

      <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CountryListBox"   PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LastNameTextBox" PropertyName="Text" />
      </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh rate"?

Comment: for example in every 5 seconds, I want to see the newest data about employees in San Andreas.

Comment: So you want the page to refresh every 5 sec and databind the table each time?

Comment: not entire page or not entire gridview, I want to refresh gridview partially and wondering is there anyway to do this.

Comment: To do it partially you still need to know which records changed or got deleted, so you need to refresh whole datasource and run the query anyway. Then I think updating part of the gridview instead of whole doesn't make sense as you already did the most time consuming part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can render partially the `GridView` data but I just made an experiment with an `UpdatePanel` and a `Timer` controls and it works nicely, the grid data is updated and since I'm paging on the server, just a small bunch of data is retrieved from the SQL Server.

The nice thing is that the current page index and order is preserved when the data is updated so it actually looks like if the grid data would be being updated partially

Take a look:

### ASPX

```
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="ods" TypeName="MyObject" EnablePaging="True"
        SelectMethod="FindPaging"
        MaximumRowsParameterName="pageSize"
        SortParameterName="sortColumn"
        StartRowIndexParameterName="startIndex"
        SelectCountMethod="FindPagingCount"
    >
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="sortColumn" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="startIndex" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pageSize" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="job" Type="String" ControlID="ddl" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

    <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="ddl" DataTextField="job_desc" DataValueField="job_id">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="10"
                DataSourceID="ods" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Timer Enabled="true" Interval="5000" runat="server" ID="timer" OnTick="timer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

### In the ASPX code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.ddl.DataSource = new DataClassesDataContext().jobs;
        this.ddl.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.grid.DataBind();
}
```

### Data Object

```
public class MyObject
{
    public IEnumerable<employee> FindPaging(string job, int startIndex, int pageSize, string sortColumn)
    {
        var c = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var sort = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortColumn) || sortColumn == "sortColumn")
        {
            sort = "fname";
        }
        else
        {
            sort = sortColumn.Replace("sortColumn ", string.Empty);
            sort = sort.Replace(" DESC", string.Empty);
        }

        var q = c.employees.Where(x => x.job_id.ToString() == job).Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize);

        if (!sortColumn.Contains("DESC"))
        {
            return q.OrderBy(sort);
        }
        else
        {
            return q.OrderByDescending(sort);
        }
    }

    public int FindPagingCount(string job, int startIndex, int pageSize, string sortColumn)
    {
        var c = new DataClassesDataContext();

        return c.employees.Where(x => x.job_id.ToString() == job).Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you use filtering in you data source?

Comment: Nope. Gimme a sec I will test using a `DropDownList`

Comment: Ok I m waiting and glad to see your interest :)

Comment: I already tested with a `DropDownList` outside of the `UpdatePanel` (for more design flexibility) using triggers to force the post when you change the value of the list and it works nicely. I didn't post the code to bind the `DropDownList`, you simply create a new data source object or bind it in code. You also need to update your select method to accept the parameter coming from the `DropDownList` control

Comment: Thanks for your effort and help.

Comment: @Jupaol, Very Nice. It would be great if you can post the complete code for user who are on a learning curve.